# Org-mode capture %g only autocompletes for some tags in my target file

Tags: emacs, elisp, capture, org-mode

I am using org-mode to collect notes for a research project, and each note I assign various tags which are shared with some other notes, or are new.

I have a long list of notes, each with tags and properties. However, when I go to capture, or I do C-c C-q or C-c C-c to assign tags to a headline, I only get an incomplete list of tags. I.e., only some of the tags in my file show up.

Here is my capture template:

```
(setq org-capture-templates
      '(("n" "Research" entry (file "~/Dropbox/University/Friendship/research.org")
             "* %? %^g %^{source}p %^{pg}p")))
```

Any idea what is wrong?

Comment: Please give a **small** example of an org-file where you get an incomplete list of tags. I assume that minimizing an org-file in this respect is half of the task done.

Answer (score 0):

You are using

> "%^g"

(lowercase);

instead you should use

> "%^G"

(uppercase).

> %^g         Prompt for tags, with completion on tags in target file.
>
> %^G         Prompt for tags, with completion on all tags in all agenda
>   files.